# Using FOR IN and dictionaries in PYTHON 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dict()ionary of random unique keys and the value to be a class object or whatever.

The problem is that when I cycle through the dictionary using FOR IN all I'm given is the key name when what I really want is a reference to a dictionary item.

Let me explain in code:

```
a = dict()
a['trees'] = dict()
a['trees']['oak'] = 453
a['trees']['pine'] = 12
a['trees']['chestnut'] = 65

for b in a['trees']:
    print b
```

The output is:

> oak
>   pine
>   chestnut

what I want is:

> {'oak' : 453}
>   {'pine' : 12}
>   {'chestnut' : 65}

I've tried:

```
FOR b in a['trees'].items():
```

But that returns tuples with copied data meaning I can't change a value and effect the original item in the dictionary.

I could do this:

```
FOR b in a['trees']:
    tree = a['trees'][b]
```

But that seems a bit long winded and I sure it can be done within the FOR statement.

I sure I'm missing something pretty simple here :/ thanks for your comments in advance guys.

Comment: What about using `dict.values` or `dict.itervalues`? You are not supposed to change the dictionary you are iterating over, but you are free to modify the (mutable) dictionaries that are contained inside the outer dictionary.

Comment: Does that make a copy of the values and return that or does it return a reference to the items value?

Comment: @cookertron give it a go and see!

Comment: No that approach doesn't work. What I'll have to do is get the key and then reference the dictionary I'm iterating over with the that.

Comment: @cookertron No copies are made if you use `itervalues` or `iteritems` (the latter is probably what you want). If you usue `values` or `items` an list is dynamically created to hold the data, but the elements itself are not copied.

Comment: ok but when I use `for k, v in a['trees'].iteritems()` changing _v_ doesn't change the original value in the dictionary.

Comment: What I'm going to have to do by the sound of it is use the key to reference the dictionary outside of the iteration. `for b in a['trees']: print a['trees'][b]`

Comment: @cookertron *reassigning* `v` won't change the original, but *mutating it* will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question , the main point seems to be -

> But that returns tuples with copied data meaning **I can't change a value and effect the original item in the dictionary.**

As you observed, when you iterate over a dictionary you get the keys, not sub dictionaries (or key/value pairs).

You can use `dict.iteritems()` and then unpack the value into key and value , and then use that to make changes to your original dictionary. Example -

```
>>> d = {1:2,3:4,5:6}
>>> for key,value in d.iteritems():
...     d[key] = value + 1
... 
>>> d
{1: 3, 3: 5, 5: 7}
```

---

Also, if accessing `a['trees'][b]` looks long to you, you can assign the reference to `a['trees']` dictionary to a shorter variable and use that for your needs. Example -

```
>>> a = dict()
>>> a['trees'] = dict()
>>> a['trees']['oak'] = 453
>>> a['trees']['pine'] = 12
>>> a['trees']['chestnut'] = 65
>>> b = a['trees']
>>> for key,value in b.iteritems():
...     b[key] = value + 100
... 
>>> a
{'trees': {'chestnut': 165, 'oak': 553, 'pine': 112}}
```

Comment: Would really like to hear how I can improve the answer, or how this is wrong.

Comment: I don't why this has been down voted it seems perfectly valid. It looks to be the best approach so far

Comment: I am guessing I got downvoted because some people mistook the main point of the question to be printing. Hopefully I have updated the correct main point of the question in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for b in a['trees']:
    print '{\'' + b + '\':' + str(a['trees'][b]) + '}'
```

output:

```
{'chestnut':65}
{'oak':453}
{'pine':12}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but the get a list of dictionaries from `a`, you can use:

```
In [14]: [dict((x,)) for x in a['trees'].items()]
Out[14]: [{'chestnut': 65}, {'oak': 453}, {'pine': 12}]
```

To get a string matching your expected output, try:

```
In [15]: print ' '.join([str(dict((x,))) for x in a['trees'].items()])
{'chestnut': 65} {'oak': 453} {'pine': 12}
```

Answer (score -1):

here your answer

```
a = dict()
    a['trees'] = dict()
    a['trees']['oak'] = 453
    a['trees']['pine'] = 12
    a['trees']['chestnut'] = 65

    for b in a:
        if a.get("trees"):
            print a.items()
```

It's possible to create lists from dictionaries by using the methods ***items(), keys() and values().*** 
As the name implies the method keys() creates a list, which consists solely of the keys of the dictionary. While values() produces a list consisting of the values. items() can be used to create a list consisting of 2-tuples of (key,value)-pairs:

```
>>> w={"house":"Haus","cat":"Katze","red":"rot"}
>>> w.items()
[('house', 'Haus'), ('red', 'rot'), ('cat', 'Katze')]
>>> w.keys()
['house', 'red', 'cat']
>>> w.values()
['Haus', 'rot', 'Katze']
```

If we apply the method items() to a dictionary, we have no information loss, i.e. it is possible to recreate the original dictionary from the list created by items(). Even though this list of 2-tuples has the same entropy, i.e. the information content is the same, the efficiency of both approaches is completely different. The dictionary data type provides highly efficient methods to access, delete and change elements of the dictionary, while in the case of lists these functions have to be implemented by the programmer.